# How to create fewer columns from a multitude of columns with NA's?

Tags: r

I have converted a long format data.frame to wide in order to merge it with another dataframe. When I transformed the long to wide I got a lot of NA's and I would like to eliminate these NA's and create some new columns with the data existing.

The long data can have multiple levels for the same ID. I want all levels to be in a wide format rather than long. Because I have more than 40 levels in the long data, when I transform it to wide using "dcast" I get a lot of columns with tons of NA's. I have tried a lot of ways to merge these columns in order to eliminate as many NA's as posible but it did not work.

My data looks like this:

```
ID | Date | Gender | Age | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | ... | NameN |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1/1      F       1     NA     Name2    Name3   NA           NameN
2    2/2      M       2     NA      NA      Name3   NA             NA
3    3/3      F       3     NA     Name2    Name3   NA             NA
4    4/4      F       4    Name1    NA      Name3   NA             NA
5    5/5      F       5     NA      NA       NA    Name4           NA
6    6/6      M       6     NA      NA       NA     NA             NA
7    7/7      F       7     NA      NA       NA     NA             NA
8    8/8      F       8     NA      NA       NA     NA             NA
```

I would like to get something that looks like this

```
ID | Date | Gender | Age | Risk1 | Risk2| ...| RiskN |
------------------------------------------------------
1    1/1      F       1    Name2   Name3 NameN    
2    2/2      M       2    Name3    NA    NA     
3    3/3      F       3    Name2   Name3  NA
4    4/4      F       4    Name1   Name3  NA
5    5/5      F       5    Name4    NA    NA
6    6/6      M       6     NA      NA    NA
7    7/7      F       7     NA      NA    NA
8    8/8      F       8     NA      NA    NA
```

Edit1: Thanks for the answers, unfortunately neither of them give the expected output. I edited the data above to include a few more entries which I have in my data and are getting excluded completely. Also I nave 45 variables (Name1, Name2 ... Name45). Based on the second answer I received I should have only 9 Risk variables left. Sorry for the confusion!

The output for the first answer is eliminating all the rows similar to 6:8 rows. Also the remaining data does not look as expected above but more like:

```
ID | Date | Gender | Age | RiskName1 | RiskName2 | RiskName3 | RiskName4 | ... | RiskNameN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4    4/4      F       4    Name1           NA       Name3         NA           NA
1    1/1      F       1     NA           Name2      Name3         NA        NameN
3    3/3      F       3     NA           Name2      Name3         NA           NA
2    2/2      M       2     NA             NA       Name3         NA           NA
5    5/5      F       5     NA             NA        NA         Name4          NA
```

The second anwer still eliminates data similar to 6:8 but performs better in terms of actually eliminating the large number of columns existing but it replaces all the row content with numbers. E.g.

```
ID | Date | Gender | Age | Risk1 | Risk2| Risk3 |
-------------------------------------------------
1    1/1      F       1      1       1      1    
2    2/2      M       2      1       0      0    
3    3/3      F       3      1       1      0
4    4/4      F       4      1       1      0
5    5/5      F       5      1       0      0
```

Edit2:
The data is sensitive, but I created a very similar structure for you to work with. Thanks!

Sample data:

`structure(list(Ref = c("213", "42", "512", "123","421"), 
Start = structure(c(1541912880, 1541912880, 1541918160,1541918160,1542024180), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),Age = c(1, 7, 8, 6, 3),
Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female","Female", "Female"), Ethnicity = c("E2",                                                                              "E1", "E4", "E1", "E1"), Cats = c("cats", "cats", NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_), Dogs = c(NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, "dogs", NA_character_), Iguanas = c(NA_character_, "Iguanas", NA_character_, "Iguanas", NA_character_), Coalas = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Ducks = c("ducks", NA_character_,"ducks",NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                     -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

How I would like it to look:

```
Ref | Date        | Gender | Age | Risk1 | Risk2| Risk3 |
---------------------------------------------------------
213    2018-11-11      F       1    cats   ducks     NA    
42     2018-11-11      M       7    cats   Iguanas   NA    
512    2018-11-11      F       8    ducks    NA      NA
123    2018-11-11      F       6    dogs   Iguanas   NA
421    2018-11-12      F       3     NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: There is no need for `Rissk3`. right?

Answer (score 3):

An option would be `gather` the 'Name' columns into 'long' format whilee removing the `NA` with `na.rm = TRUE`, then grouped by 'ID', create the 'Risk' as a sequence column and `spread` back to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Risk, val, starts_with("Name"), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(Risk = str_c("Risk", Risk)) %>%
      spread(Risk, val)
```

---

With new updated dataset

```
df2 %>%
  gather(Risk, val,  Cats:Ducks) %>% 
  mutate(Ref = factor(Ref, levels = unique(Ref))) %>% 
  arrange(Ref, is.na(val)) %>%
  group_by(Ref) %>%
  slice(if(all(is.na(val))) 1 else which(!is.na(val))) %>% 
  mutate(Risk = str_c('Risk', row_number())) %>%
  spread(Risk, val)
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   Ref [5]
#  Ref   Start                 Age Gender Ethnicity Risk1 Risk2  
#  <fct> <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>  
#1 213   2018-11-11 05:08:00     1 Female E2        cats  ducks  
#2 42    2018-11-11 05:08:00     7 Male   E1        cats  Iguanas
#3 512   2018-11-11 06:36:00     8 Female E4        ducks <NA>   
#4 123   2018-11-11 06:36:00     6 Female E1        dogs  Iguanas
#5 421   2018-11-12 12:03:00     3 Female E1        <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: @AndreiT. Can you update with a `dput` of your dataset as it gives thee structure reproducible

Comment: Done. Edit2 above

Comment: @AndreiT. The column name are different.  YOu may need `gather(df2, Risk, val, Cats:Ducks, na.rm = TRUE) %>% group_by(Ref) %>% mutate(Risk = str_c("Risk", Risk)) %>% spread(Risk, val)`

Comment: I did change the `starts_with("Name")` in the initial reponse and it did not work. I tried your response again on my mock data and it does delete the last entry  and I still get four variables (cats, Dogs, Ducks and Iguanas) instead of getting two Risk columns as I wanted.

Comment: @AndreiT. let me check

Comment: @AndreiT. I updated the post.  I think the last column 'Risk3' have only NAs.  so, i removed it

Answer (score 2):

Similar convert to long then back to wide approach, with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

long <- melt(df, which(!names(df) %like% 'Name'), na.rm = T)

dcast(long[, -'variable'], ... ~ paste0('Risk', rowid(ID)))

#    Date Gender Age Risk1 Risk2
# 1:  1/1      F   1 Name2 Name3
# 2:  2/2      M   2 Name3  <NA>
# 3:  3/3      F   3 Name2 Name3
# 4:  4/4      F   4 Name1 Name3
# 5:  5/5      F   5 Name4  <NA>
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
ID  Date  Gender  Age  Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4 
1    1/1      F       1     NA     Name2    Name3   NA
2    2/2      M       2     NA      NA      Name3   NA
3    3/3      F       3     NA     Name2    Name3   NA
4    4/4      F       4    Name1    NA      Name3   NA
5    5/5      F       5     NA      NA       NA    Name4
')
```